# Product cards title same height per row issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can anyone suggest what is the best way to make cards title same height per row so my images align on the same line at the bottom. I am looking for a responsive solution. Any CSS tricks or jQuery plugins? I have been Googling around, but have not found any similar solutions.

Note keep in mind that absolute height for title will not work as during browser resize titles will break to more lines that still need to be calculated again. Thanks

Ideal end result:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IeQ6X7R9utZzKTn8UdNFruInezJpX1V_/view?usp=sharing

```
See in codepen
```

https://codepen.io/edvardsniedre/pen/ymBdwg

Comment: I was not very clear with description so I have updated my post and added image to demonstrate what I am looking for. Thanks for all replies so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I have found this plugin that have solved it for me.
https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height 
Working demo: https://codepen.io/edvardsniedre/pen/ymBdwg

Answer (score 1):

@user2713970 I think this code will help you, check this out.

```
           <style>
            * { box-sizing: border-box; }

            .card_image { width:100%; height:150px; }
            body { 
              max-width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 40px 10px;
            }

            .cards 
            {  display: flex; justify-content: space-between; flex-wrap: wrap; }

            .card {
                width: 24%; border: 1px solid black;
                margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;    
            }

            img { width: 100%; }

            .title { padding: 10px 0; }



            @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
              .cards {
                .card {
                  width: 49%;
                }
              }
            }



            <body>
                <div class="cards">
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="card_image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRfwXs8u99aFJFdhPx7oIgK1dLCkqQ14U7Yn4n1nvEwi_rgiWeYfg" alt="">
                    <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
                    <div>$20</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="card_image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQKa0uIGrJO2QhidOcpE15BSVHK5uK3NNpH0ooXliy89IjeyK-bg" alt="">
                    <div class="title">Title Title Title </div>
                    <div>$20</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="card_image" src="https://envato-shoebox-0.imgix.net/4646/3935-85f4-41a0-b940-708875ee0a15/tajak+019.jpg?w=500&h=278&fit=crop&crop=edges&auto=compress%2Cformat&s=c45335aca948555287bc4229b1632950" alt="">
                    <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
                    <div>$20</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="card_image" src="http://3v6x691yvn532gp2411ezrib-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/imagetext01.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
                    <div>$20</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="card_image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535498730771-e735b998cd64?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
                    <div>$20</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="card_image" src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--PnSCSSFQ--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,pg_1,q_80,w_800/z7jcryloxjedsztssw39.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
                    <div>$20</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="card_image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/28/22/11/message-in-a-bottle-3437294__340.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
                    <div>$20</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card">
                    <img class="card_image" src="https://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2018/03/italy_and_mediterranean/17402074-1-eng-GB/Italy_and_Mediterranean_node_full_image_2.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="title">Title</div>
                    <div>$20</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `height` on the `.title` class, however, that won't automatically adjust to different size titles.  The setting below is only sufficient for your current content.

```
  .title {
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 120px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

@user2713970 as per your css now you are only setting padding to the title so your title is wrapping text that's why your height is uneven.

**Current CSS:**

```
.title {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

If you set your title with fixed height then the title will have the same height for all rows and also your image will automatically align to title top. (There is no need for using jquery)

**Change To**

```
.title {
     padding: 10px 0;
     height: 150px
 }
```

Here is [Codepen](https://codepen.io/nick4434/pen/BXarQv?editors=1100) For Better understanding.
[*also in the second line of cards in codepen demo have a vertical-align title for the understanding of alignment.*]

Comment: This is not a good solution because you're hard-coding height for the title. It might work when text doesn't exceed the height but it will break otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Since your title content is variable length, there aren't many ways to keep all images aligned on the same line at the bottom. That said, there are some. One of them would be to set a `min-height` and `max-height` on the title and use Webkit's proprietary `-webkit-line-clamp` property (and some attendant, required styles) to truncate all overflow text that doesn't fit neatly within the clamped lines. Browser support for this is decent, but you'll miss IE and Android FF. The `line-clamp` property is currently at the Editor's Draft status. The implementation may change as it moves toward its final state in the spec. So, this isn't a great cross-browser solution.

But I don't see how you can accomplish what you're after without truncating text that doesn't fit a specified height on the title. Maybe someone else knows a way.

Check out the solution below, but also know that there are other options out there to accomplish the same goal but with broader support: [Clamp.js](https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js) is one of them.

For an overview of other strategies for truncating overflow text, see [this](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/) article on CSS Tricks.

As an aside, and you may already have this in the works, I'd consider setting a height on your images and using `object-fit:cover` to keep them aligned while having them fill up the available space nicely. I've taken the liberty of implementing that in the code below, but I've commented where I made those optional changes.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      max-width: 960px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 40px 10px;
    }

    .cards {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .card {
      width: 24%;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-top: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      /* CHANGED FROM FLEX-END TO SPACE-BETWEEN */
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    img {
      width: 100%;
      /* OPTIONAL OBJECT-FIT STYLES */
      height: 65%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }

    .title {
      padding: 10px 0;
      min-height: 75px;
      max-height: 75px;
      overflow: hidden;
      visibility: visible;
      display: -webkit-box;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      line-height: 1.5;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
      .cards .card {
        width: 49%;

      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRfwXs8u99aFJFdhPx7oIgK1dLCkqQ14U7Yn4n1nvEwi_rgiWeYfg" alt="">
      <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
      <div class="price">$20</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQKa0uIGrJO2QhidOcpE15BSVHK5uK3NNpH0ooXliy89IjeyK-bg" alt="">
      <div class="title">Title Title Title </div>
      <div class="price">$20</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://envato-shoebox-0.imgix.net/4646/3935-85f4-41a0-b940-708875ee0a15/tajak+019.jpg?w=500&h=278&fit=crop&crop=edges&auto=compress%2Cformat&s=c45335aca948555287bc4229b1632950" alt="">
      <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
      <div class="price">$20</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="http://3v6x691yvn532gp2411ezrib-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/imagetext01.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
      <div class="price">$20</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535498730771-e735b998cd64?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
      <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
      <div class="price">$20</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--PnSCSSFQ--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,pg_1,q_80,w_800/z7jcryloxjedsztssw39.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
      <div class="price">$20</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/28/22/11/message-in-a-bottle-3437294__340.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
      <div class="price">$20</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2018/03/italy_and_mediterranean/17402074-1-eng-GB/Italy_and_Mediterranean_node_full_image_2.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="price">$20</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I was not very clear with description so I have updated my post and added image to demonstrate what I am looking for. Thanks for all replies so far. This is a great solution but my designer wants all items in the card to be aligned to the bottom. Please see image attached.

Comment: I see your updated post with image. Interesting challenge. I'll look into it soon unless someone else posts a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do this without resorting to JavaScript (which I'm sure could be optimized and cleaned up).

¯_(ツ)_/¯

Best of luck.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      max-width: 960px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 40px 10px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .cards {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .card {
      flex: 0 0 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .img-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: flex-end;
    }

    .details {
      background-color: white;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    img {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      margin-top: auto;
    }

    .price {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 560px) {
      .card {
        flex: 0 0 50%;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
      .card {
        flex: 0 0 25%;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRfwXs8u99aFJFdhPx7oIgK1dLCkqQ14U7Yn4n1nvEwi_rgiWeYfg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
        <div class="price">$20</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQKa0uIGrJO2QhidOcpE15BSVHK5uK3NNpH0ooXliy89IjeyK-bg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <div class="title">Title Title Title </div>
        <div class="price">$20</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="https://envato-shoebox-0.imgix.net/4646/3935-85f4-41a0-b940-708875ee0a15/tajak+019.jpg?w=500&h=278&fit=crop&crop=edges&auto=compress%2Cformat&s=c45335aca948555287bc4229b1632950" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
        <div class="price">$20</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="http://3v6x691yvn532gp2411ezrib-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/imagetext01.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
        <div class="price">$20</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535498730771-e735b998cd64?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
        <div class="price">$20</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--PnSCSSFQ--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,pg_1,q_80,w_800/z7jcryloxjedsztssw39.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
        <div class="price">$20</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/28/22/11/message-in-a-bottle-3437294__340.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
        <div class="price">$20</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="https://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2018/03/italy_and_mediterranean/17402074-1-eng-GB/Italy_and_Mediterranean_node_full_image_2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <div class="title">Title</div>
        <div class="price">$20</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {


      function setImageHeight() {
        var imageWrapper = document.querySelectorAll('.img-wrapper');
        var elems = [].slice.call(imageWrapper);
        var tallest = Math.max.apply(Math, elems.map(function (elem, index) {
          elem.style.minHeight = '';
          return elem.offsetHeight;
        }));

        elems.forEach(function (elem, index, arr) {
          elem.style.minHeight = tallest + 'px';
        });
      }

      function setTitleHeight() {
        var title = document.querySelectorAll('.title');
        var elems = [].slice.call(title);
        var tallest = Math.max.apply(Math, elems.map(function (elem, index) {
          elem.style.minHeight = '';
          return elem.offsetHeight;
        }));

        elems.forEach(function (elem, index, arr) {
          elem.style.minHeight = tallest + 'px';
        });
      }
      setTimeout(function () {
        setImageHeight();
        setTitleHeight();
      }, 250);
      var resized = true;
      var timeout = null;
      var refresh = function () {
        if (resized) {
          requestAnimationFrame(setImageHeight);
          requestAnimationFrame(setTitleHeight);
        }
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(refresh, 100);
        resized = false;
      };
      window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
        resized = true;
      });
      refresh();
    });

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, JS looks like the only way to solve it. This is pretty much a solution for me. The only thing I need to calculate title same height per row. If I set all row titles to the same height, then in case where the row will have one line titles, space between title and price will be unnecessary big, like in the picture. I just need to figure out how to do the same thing per row, taking in account that the row column count will change per breakpoint from lets say 4 to 2.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hr22U3-_iQeJAL3Y14WDDAiSsajevgPn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: After tinkering around your idea I have found this plugin which does all the magic for me in on line of code. Yay!
Plugin: https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height
Working demo: https://codepen.io/edvardsniedre/pen/ymBdwg